# Multi Section Rounded Block

Tags: html, css

how can i make this type of section. I have tried a lot but not able to make proper rounded corner. It need to smooth.

Desired Result [image]

Here is my code

```css
.section {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.section:nth-child(odd):after {
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
.section:nth-child(even):before {
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
.section:before, .section:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
.section:after {
  border: solid purple;
  border-width: 5px 0;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.section:before {
  border: solid orange;
  border-width: 5px 0;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    
</div>
<div class="section">
    
</div>
<div class="section">
    
</div>
<div class="section">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

```css
.section {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 30px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.section:nth-child(odd):after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  height:20px;
  bottom:0;
  width:50%;
  border-right:2px solid blue;
  border-bottom:2px solid blue;
  border-radius:0 0 20px 0;
}
.section:nth-child(odd):before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  height:20px;
  bottom:-20px;
  width:50%;
  border-left:2px solid green;
  border-top:2px solid green;
  border-radius:20px 0 0 0;
}

.section:nth-child(even):after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  height:20px;
  bottom:-20px;
  width:50%;
  border-right:2px solid blue;
  border-top:2px solid blue;
  border-radius:0 20px 0 0;
}
.section:nth-child(even):before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  height:20px;
  bottom:0;
  width:50%;
  border-left:2px solid green;
  border-bottom:2px solid green;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    
</div>
<div class="section">
    
</div>
<div class="section">
    
</div>
<div class="section">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Hey mate, can you help me to solve this issue too :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369061/how-to-skew-from-css-for-this-spape