# How to skew from css for this shape?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make like this block but wasn't able to make as in the design. How can I make it? Can you help me? Here is desired block [image]

and code I have tried:

```css
.section-1 {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.section-2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.col-img {
  margin-top: -40px;
  position: relative;
}

.col-img:after {
  top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background: purple;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
}

.col-img  img{
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.section-2 .col {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
  
</div>
<div class="section-2">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum voluptatem beatae quia facilis nobis, dolore quidem nostrum! Blanditiis eveniet dolor a, laudantium repudiandae rem commodi ea adipisci. Eius, obcaecati rerum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-img">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x650" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider multiple background and some border like this like this:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.box {
  padding:40px calc(100% - 250px) 10px 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-top:30px solid lightblue;
  border-bottom:5px solid yellow;
  height:350px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(120deg, lightblue 280px,transparent 280px)0 0/100% 40px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(120deg,white 250px,yellow 250px,yellow 280px,transparent 280px)0 0/100% 100% no-repeat,
  url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/) 0 0/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Or more easier way with more element and some transformation:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.box {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-top:30px solid lightblue;
  border-bottom:5px solid yellow;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  background:url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/) 0 0/cover no-repeat;
}
.content {
  padding:20px 5px 0 30px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:40%;
  border-top:20px solid lightblue;
  background:linear-gradient(yellow,yellow) 100% 0/10px 100% no-repeat;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
  background-color:#fff;
}
.content span{
  display:inline-block;
  transform:skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="content">
<span> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [CSS3 `transform`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) property, to skew your image. You can use either the `skewX()` or `skewY()` functions, or you can `rotate()`.

```
.col-img {
    transform:rotate(25deg);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i have tried but there is left border and image will go negative on top section too.